# Porque este script está me retornando um objeto?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou trabalhando com jQuery para cadastro de informações no banco de dados através do Ajax e não sei porque este código está me retornando uma variável do tipo objeto. O projeto no qual estou trabalhando está sendo desenvolvido em cima de um `Admin Panel` com toda a interface e `HTML, CSS e JS` prontos. Eis o código:

```
$("#cadastra_produtos").submit(function(){

    var prod_nome       = $("#prod_nome");
    var prod_categoria  = $("#prod_categoria");
    var prod_dimens     = $("#prod_dimens");
    var prod_qtde       = $("#prod_qtde");
    var prod_valor      = $("#prod_valor");
    var prod_descr      = $("#prod_descr");

    if(prod_nome) { alert(prod_nome); } <-- isso me retorna um objeto
```

A única particularidade deste formulário que eu acho que poderia estar gerando algum erro do tipo é o plugin `chosen-select` que faz parte do front-end do sistema.

Podem me ajudar a descobrir o motivo do alert me mostrar um objeto e não a string?

Comment: Faltou pegar o `.val()` de todos os campos. O objeto que você está vendo é o objeto do jQuery que embrulha o campo em questão.

Comment: Nota: `if(prod_nome)` **nunca** vai cair no `else`.

Comment: Nooooooooooooossa esqueci o `val()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parece que você já percebeu mas para fins didáticos..

no exemplo:

html

```
<input id="prod_name" />
```

javascript

```
var nome = $("#prod_nome");
```

**nome** recebe um objeto encapsulado pelo jQuery para manipular o objeto DOM que representa o `<input />` no JavaScript logo para acessar seu valor deve-se usar o `.val()` ficando

```
var nome = $("#prod_nome").val();
```